# Not able to Type anything in input field inside pure-react-carousel

Tags: reactjs, forms, pure-react-carousel

I am working on a functionality of a multi-step form with pure-react-carousel. I am using custom components (which are forms) as slides but not able to type anything in the input field, the input field is not getting focused on clicking them in any of the slides. Can someone please help me, how can I enable typing in the input fields?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution. I just focused input field on click and it works fine.